# Meteor - How do you exclude properties in a child collection from being published?

Tags: meteor, publish

Imagine you have a collection similar to the following...

```
Tests = [
  {
    name: 'Some Test',
    questions: [
      { question: 'Answer to life, the universe, and everything?', answer: '42' },
      { question: 'What is your favorite color?', answer: 'Blue' },
      { question: 'Airspeed velocity of unladen European Swallow?', answer: '24 mph' }
    ]
  }
];
```

**How do you publish the entire collection except for the answer property?**

I understand you can do the following to omit properties from the publish...

```
Meteor.publish('tests', function() {
  return Tests.find({}, {fields: {name:0}});
});
```

But I'm not sure how to omit a property from an array property.

Thanks!

Comment: It must be something like 
`return Tests.find({}, {fields: {'questions.$.answer':0}});`
But it seems to be unsupported yet

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done the way you want to do it.  Meteor only supports field specifiers that are 1 level deep.  You can sometimes get a sub-field specifier to work, but it's not reliable.

You can put your questions into their own collection with a testId field that links them back to the test, relational style.  One question per document, and then you'll be able to specify that only the question field gets published.

```
Meteor.publish ('questions', function(testId) {
    return Questions.find({testId: testId}, {fields: {question: 1}})
});
```

It's not ideal, but pretty painless compared to trying to find a workaround that allows your questions to live in the test document.

There might be a way to do this manually with a more involved publish.  There's a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25349873/meteor-mongodb-get-part-of-array-through-subscription) with an answer that gets into it.