# Meteor/Mongo get a specific document in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, document

Considering:

```
{
  docs: Array[{field1, field2}]
}
```

I know how to find the document(s) containing `field1` or `field2` with `$elemMatch`, but my question is **how can I get the value of field1 knowing field2?**

I also know that in MongoDB you would use `$elemMatch` in the *projection* parameter. Or that I can do this in JS with something like `_.find()`, but the goal is to get only one specific document from Mongo.

Let say for example a document:

```
{
  _id: 1
  docs: [{a: 42, b:"stringX"}, {a:0, b:"stringY"}]
}
```

How can I get the value of *a* (42) knowing *b* ("stringX")?

Is there something like: MyCollection.findOne({_id: 1}, *projection: {docs:{b: "stringX"}}*) ?

Answer (score 1):

On the *server* you can use this projection:

```
var a = MyCollection.findOne({'docs.b': "stringX"},{fields: {'docs.$': 1}}).a;
```

However the `$` array projection does not work on the client in minimongo (yet).

Hopefully this is sufficient to get you unstuck.

See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25353962/2805154)

Comment: Thank you for your response. But my goal is not to get the first but the **specific** document. I already did it in JS with `_.find() ` but I'm looking for a Meteor / Mongo solution as lots of documents will be returned if I don't do it properly. _Just edited my question accordingly, sorry for the confusion_

Comment: Then you need `$elemMatch` in the projection! See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12241930/2805154

Comment: As I said in the question, I know we can do it in Mongo with projection. My question is how to do it in Meteor collections ?

Comment: A Meteor collection is a mongo collection. *Most* of the mongo syntax applies directly in Meteor. There are a few things that don't work or where the syntax is slightly different.

Comment: Ok, then can you give me the answer for my case please? :) Because I really looked everywhere on Meteor docs. Unlike Mongo, I don't see any "projection" option on Meteor's `.find()` or `.findOne()` methods.